# altering table using php-mysql

Tags: php, sql

I want to add a new field to the table techs.But it doesn't work.What have I done wrong?

```
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cs1");

$a=" ALTER TABLE techs ADD j INT";

$query1 = mysqli_query($connect, $a);
```

Comment: `Doesn't work`, the favorite error message of SO. As the real error messages (like the ones given with `mysqli_error($connect)`) are soooo boring.

Comment: post any other code that you think is related to this.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: No error.Column j doesn't get add up on my table

Comment: The query works.I checked with this code and otput was altered.if `($query1 === TRUE) {
 echo "altered"; 
} else {
 echo "couldn't alter"; 
}`

Comment: Hope some one can help me / if u need help.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640395/alter-table-contents-dynamicly-with-php-html-and-mysql